# Solve the non-linear DE $y' = xy+ y^{1/2}$ analytically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've tried the Bernoulli Eq technique, $y=ux$ substitution technique, but nothing seemed to work out. Any ideas?

Comment: I take it that you think of $y'=xy+y^{1/2}$ otherwise the equation is linear.

Comment: @Kenisha please check if the formatting corresponds to your DE.

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=u^2$ so $y'=2uu'=xu^2+u\Rightarrow u'=\frac 12xu+\frac12$. Solve for $u$ using integrating factor and then find $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$y'=xy+y^{1/2} \implies y'-xy=y^{1/2}$

So taking $p(x)=-x,q(x)=1, n={1/2}$

We have $y'+p(x)=q(x)y^n$

[Applying Bernoulli's Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html)

$$y^{1-n}=\frac{(1-n)\int e^{(1-n)\int p(x)dx}q(x)dx+c_1}{e^{(1-n)\int p(x)dx}}$$

Plugging in some terms we get 
$$y^{1/2}=\frac{(1/2)\int e^{(-x^2/4)}dx+c_1}{e^{(-x^2/4)}}$$

$$y^{1/2}=\frac{(\sqrt{\pi}/2)\operatorname{erf}(x/2)+c_1}{e^{(-x^2/4)}}$$

$$y^{1/2}=e^{(x^2/4)}\bigg((\sqrt{\pi}/2)\operatorname{erf}(x/2)+c_1 \bigg)$$

$$y=\frac{\pi}{4}e^{(x^2/2)}\bigg(\operatorname{erf}(x/2)+c_1 \bigg)^2$$

Where $\operatorname{erf}(z) =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2} dt $ is the error [function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Guacho Perez answered, starting with $y=u^2$, you end with

$$u \left(-2 u'+x u+1\right)=0$$ Excluding the trivial case $u=0$, you then need to solve
$$2u'-xu=-1$$ Consider first 
$$2u'-xu=0 \implies \frac{u'}u=\frac x 2\implies \log(u)=\frac {x^2} 4+C\implies u=C e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}$$ Now, use the integration factor or the variation of parameters to get
$$2 e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} C'(x)=1\implies C'=\frac 12  e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}\implies C=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+K$$ then $u$ and $y$

Comment: I'm probably not at as great as a school as you've  all attended. I'm in Ohio. I haven't been taught error functions nor was aware of them.